# DockerFile: Add supporting referenced projects in the docker copy command

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile

We have microservices projects written according to the following hierarchy

```
----BaseDir
      |-----Services
               |--------Microservices
                              |-----------Docker file
      |-----ClassLibraries
               |--------Project1
               |--------Project2
```

Now we are facing a problem when the `docker build` command gets executed. MicroService Project is referencing some projects under ClassLibraries folder.

Following is the content of docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build

ADD ["../../ClassLibraries/Project1/Code/*.*","./"]
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service1.dll"]
```

when we run `docker build` command then we are getting following error:

```
ADD failed: no source files were specified
```

Answer (score 2):

`docker build` only has access to its context (files in the same folder as the `Dockerfile` and below) when doing `ADD`. As such, you can't reference parent folders in this way. You'll unfortunately need to restructure your folder layout to get this to work.